# What Does the Movie Icon in the Bitizens Album Mean?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Each special bitizen in the album has a picture and a description after they've been unlocked.  Some bitizens have a movie icon in the top right hand corner of their profile.

I have not been able to figure out what the movie icon symbolizes.

At first, I thought it meant that bitizen has unlocked a scene, but even bitizens that have not been unlocked have the icon.

[image: Darth is locked, but unlocks scenes]

Then, I thought it meant that the bitizen has the ability to unlock a scene, but then I came across a bitizen that unlocks a scene but does not have the icon.

[image: Imperial Gunner unlocks a scene, but doesn't have an icon]

And of course, there are bitizens that don't unlock anything (that I've found) that have a movie icon.

[image: Akbar doesn't unlock anything, but has the movie icon]

It doesn't seem to be completely random, as characters that unlock scenes are more likely to have the icon than those that don't.  And, characters that don't have the icon are not very likely to unlock a scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it is a "character" and not just a species or type of character.

In other words, if a character with one of these icons is sent to a level, they are recognized as themselves, and not just their species.

The only exceptions would be the Jawa and Tusken Raider.  But, I believe even they are recognized by the other bitizens.

By recognized, I mean that when they are delivered to a level, they trigger a buying frenzy, and when you look in the Holonet there is frequently a comment about them having come to that level.

This is the only thing that I have been able to observe that would earn them a distinction.

Comment: Jawa also has that exception.  I haven't noticed buying frenzies associated with dropping them off, but I haven't paid particularly close attention to it.

Comment: Fixed it above to reflect that.

Comment: I guess you can look upon the clapper icon as a symbol of celebrity status. When characters with the icon turn up on their floors, the bitizens become all excited lol.

Comment: @Han -  I agree.